# cpu requirements for `x86intrin.h`?

Tags: c++, random, intel, intrinsics

Hi there I thought the minimum CPU requirements to run `x86intrin.h` is an intel 3th gen processor.

however when i run this code

```
_rdseed64_step(&temp2);
```

i get the following error

```
error: inlining failed in call to always_inline 'int _rdseed64_step(long long unsigned int*)': target specific option mismatch
```

_rdseed64_step (unsigned long long *__p)

I have set the flag to `march=native` and it only occurs when i am using my desktop, when i run on my laptop that is running a 6th gen processor it works fine.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] and note your compiler and its version.

Comment: "Intel 3rd generation processor" is usually considered the Intel [386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) series (if not counting [186](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80186), in which case the third is the [286](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286)). Don't you mean the 3rd generation [*Core*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core) architecture (i.e. [Ivy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_(microarchitecture)))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Intel knowledge base](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523865?language=en):

> The corresponding 4th Generation Intel® Core™ instruction is RDSEED.

So it looks like you can not use it on 3th gen processor.

Comment: what's the equivalent of RDSEED for the 3th gen processor?

Comment: @albusSimba I guess there is no equivalent. You may want to perform a feature check prior to calling it. See [Intel® Digital Random Number Generator (DRNG) Software Implementation Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide)

Comment: @albusSimba: There's `rdrand` (IvyBridge and newer, and some AMD I think), but it doesn't provide as strong a guarantee.  Using multiple `rdrand` results may not be suitable for seeding the state of a PRNG, at least in theory if it needs to be cryptographically secure.  A PRNG with only 64 bits or less of state can be safely seeded by `rdrand`, though.